# TCPDF split page is as large as whole PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

After creating a PDF using TCPDF I need to split the PDF into single PDF pages. This is needed for a print service I'm using. I can do this with the PDFSAM app. It works great. 
I only have one big issue. The generated pages are each 120 MB, while the source PDF (240 pages) is in total 130 MB. These single pages are way too large for processing it through the print service.

I stripped the pdf generation code to the minimum and still have the same issue. This is the code:

```
$this->_pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, "A5", true, 'UTF-8', false);
$this->_pdf->AddPage();
$this->_pdf->Image($photo_path, 2, 2, 120, 180);

$this->_pdf->AddPage();
$this->_pdf->Image($photo_path, 2, 2, 120, 180);
... repeated code ...
```

The same problem occurs when I split the PDF with Acrobat Pro.

Are there any suggestions? It seems to me that the data in the PDF is covered over all pages or something.

Comment: just one page is 120 mb mean..what is in that page !!!! i dont think its a tcpdf issue ...

Comment: as you created it in the first place, why not create single pages, rather than creating then splitting it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your fast reply. @Dagon, Actually the splitting is done by the print service party. I can only send them a single PDF. They split it. 
They contacted me because of this problem, and asked me to figure it out. And I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: how are they doing the splitting?

Comment: They split it in Acrobat Pro. I'm splitting it in PDFSAM. They both have the same problem

Comment: First step is to identify what is getting left in the split files.  Remember a PDF is not like some sort of image, you can cut off at a tear here mark.  It's more like a program with object data.  If each page reuses given data, then each split will include it.  Each page may not use all the data, but the splitter may not know that and err on the side of caution.  Use PDF Analysis in Acrobat Pro to see what's in the split PDFs.

Comment: I think you are embedding fonts and pictures in PDF File and I would suggest you embedding subset only and don't use ASCII85 coding on streams as it make the file big and another thing clean all the objects near your major text/pic, even if you hide them they are also included so delete them before export and to find the objects in page kindly use crtl A command which gives the view of which data is going to export from your page